# Compare data of table from two different Database

Tags: oracle

I have two separate database in two separate servers. Both these database have same table . I just wanted to compare similar tables wrt to the data contained.
Also to access one database from other database do I need to create a DBLink

Comment: Quite an open ended question.  Can you please post your findings too?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to find anything in Google? There are millions of posts for this topic.

Use this [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28324/tdpii_diverge.htm#TDPII093) to learn about `dbms_comparison` package